# peewee datetime giving time server went up not current datetime

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, peewee

I have the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990080/in-peewee-i-have-a-datetime-field-defaulted-to-datetime-datetime-now-but-when#33314937). But after using the proposed answer - changing `default=datetime.now()` to `default=datetime.now` which should defer calling it, it is still giving the same timestamp for different models when created.

What else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to delete my question, but this was a stupid error which is now fixed!